# Pandas merging on column index OR naming columns without knowing how many

Tags: python, pandas

I have no idea how to solve the problem I have. I want to merge 2 dataframes:

```
show = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=0)
```

but since both dataframes are varying so much everytime I call my function I don't know how many columns are there, so I can't name them. The merge function needs column NAME to work. I tried to provide only column number but it didn't work:

```
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '0'
```

Is there any way I can merge dataframes without using column name. Alternatively- is there any way I can name columns without ever knowing how many are there?

@jezrael it still shows an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Patryk/PycharmProjects/foliumtesting/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    main(files)
  File "C:/Users/Patryk/PycharmProjects/foliumtesting/main.py", line 23, in main
    show = pd.merge(poco_df, punkty, how='left', on=poco_df.columns[0])
  File "C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 73, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 627, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 983, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1692, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select columns names by indexing, here:

```
how = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=df1.columns[0])
```

If need merge by first columns in both:

```
how = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=df1.columns[0], right_on=df2.columns[0])
```

If need merge by intersection of columns in both DataFrames remove `on` parameter:

```
how = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
```